# jquery tooltip into display:column

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, displaytag

i'm using displayTag to show some tables. I want to add a tooltip to display:column using jquery

Here is my code:

```
<c:set var="titleName"><wp:i18n key="FILENAME"/></c:set>
<display:column  title="${titleName}" class="nowrap">       
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.infoTooltip${docFinancial_rowNum}').tooltip({ 
            items: 'span',
            content: "<c:out value="${docFinancial.fileNameToDisplay}" />" }).tooltip("open");;
    });
</script>           
<span id="infoTooltip${docFinancial_rowNum}"> <c:out value="${fn:substring(docFinancial.fileNameToDisplay, 0, 20)}" />...</span>
</display:column>
```

But it's not working.. the tooltip is never displayed and i have no js error

this is the HTML source generated code

```
<td class="nowrap"><script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#infoTooltip14').tooltip({ 
                items: 'span',
                content: "I-B_2.1_529_AQUAKNIGHT_Budget A Contingency_I-B_2.1_529_AQUAKNIGHT_budget approved_customized_b" }).tooltip("open");
        });
    </script>           
    <span id="infoTooltip14"> I-B_2.1_529_AQUAKNIG...</span>
    </td>
```

What's wrong?

Thanks

andrea

Comment: Solved: i simply used the span title attribute without jquery :-P 
It's not the same when rendered but it works

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `#` to target element by `id`, you also need to escape special characters using double backslashes `\\`:

```
$('#infoTooltip\\$\\{docFinancial_rowNum\\}').tooltip({ 
// ^-- Use # instead of .
```

---

Try to use attribute start with selector:

```
$('[id^="infoTooltip"]').tooltip({
```

Comment: oops ... sorry it was my mistake copying code... i used the # to target element id but it doesn't work anyway

Comment: i tryed it.. same result. it seems that the jquery object is not associated with html object ... even if in the html source code for the page everything looks good

Comment: What is the generated HTML of your code? Can you view the source of your page?

Comment: Does your `td` wrap inside any `tr` and `table`? Otherwise, it's invalid HTML markup and will not work as expected.

Comment: the html is correct as it is generated by displayTag library.. I have not given everything for synthesis... the table is correctly displayed

Comment: same result... the tooltip is not displayed